# Two blank lines are left after formatting with Black

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been using Black for formatting my Python code, and it's been working great overall. However, I've noticed that Black always inserts two blank lines before top-level function and class definitions, and I'd like to adjust that.

**Problem:**

- After running Black, I end up with two blank lines after every function or class definition, and I want to reduce it to just one blank line.

**Question:**

- Is there a way to configure Black to leave only one blank line after function and class definitions? Or should I consider using a different formatter or linter that allows more customization?

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help.

**What I've Tried:**

- I've checked the Black documentation, but I couldn't find a direct configuration option to control the number of blank lines after formatting.
- I've manually adjusted the code after running Black, but that did not work either.

Comment: *"Black always inserts two blank lines before top-level function and class definitions"* That's what PEP8 recommends - https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#blank-lines Generally, Black's stated purpose is to be an "uncompromising code formatter" in which "style configuration options are deliberately limited and rarely added", so it's unlikely to give you a way of diverging from PEP8 here.

Comment: The yapf formatter does apparently let you configure this: https://github.com/google/yapf#blank_lines_around_top_level_definition

Comment: Why do you want to switch from two lines to one? Personal preference or? Cause that'd raise the question of why you're using Black if you want to customize things since ["By using it, you agree to cede control over minutiae of hand-formatting."](https://pypi.org/project/black/)

Answer (score 1):

Black, designed to be an uncompromising formatter, adheres strictly to **PEP 8 guidelines**. This includes the enforcement of two blank lines before top-level function and class definitions, a rule it won't bend for custom preferences.

Black's philosophy centers around providing a consistent style with as few configuration options as possible. So, if you've already combed through the Black documentation and found no flexibility in this regard, it's not an oversight—it's by design.

Possible solutions are:

- Try other formatters like **YAPF** or **autopep8**. These tools offer greater flexibility and can be configured to match your specific style requirements.
- If you're keen on keeping Black's benefits but need that extra bit of customization, crafting a post-processing script could be your ticket.
  A simple example could we count consecutive blank lines (**blank_line_count**) and only remove a blank line if there are two or more before a **def** or **class**.:

```
def adjust_blank_lines(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        content = file.readlines()

    new_content = []
    pattern = re.compile(r'^\s*(def|class) ')
    blank_line_count = 0

    for line in content:
        if pattern.match(line):
            if blank_line_count >= 2:
                # Remove one of the two blank lines
                new_content.pop()
            blank_line_count = 0
        else:
            if line.strip() == '':
                blank_line_count += 1
            else:
                blank_line_count = 0

        new_content.append(line)

    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(new_content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    adjust_blank_lines(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Thank you for the insightful information about Black's design philosophy. It's clear that Black prioritizes strict adherence to PEP 8 guidelines, including the two blank lines before top-level function and class definitions.

In light of this, I'm exploring alternative formatters like autopep8. Before making the switch, I'm curious to know how autopep8 handles the two blank lines requirement. Could someone provide insights or guidance on configuring autopep8 to maintain this specific aspect of the formatting?

I appreciate any assistance or recommendations in this regard. Thank you!

Comment: Comments and answers have pointed the way.